# Cant Create SQL Table [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Im not sure what is wrong with my create table here. Keeps giving me error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
    near 'character
(
character_id VarChar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
name VarChar(30) NOT NULL,
sex' at line 1
```

I dont see any errors in it?

```
CREATE TABLE character
(
character_id VarChar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
name VarChar(30) NOT NULL,
sex VarChar(7) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
hair VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
eye VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
skin VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
body VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
from VarChar(20) NOT NULL
) engine=innobd;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`character` and `from` are reserved words in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

To use a reserved word as a field/table identifier, you'll have to quote it with backticks:

```
create table `character` (
...
body VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
`from` VarChar(20) NOT NULL
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew that as soon as you said I just thought fail.

Answer (score 0):

Both *from* and *character* are special words reserved by the database vendor. Try, for example, naming a column "limit" and you will get the same result. Re-name the table and the column *from* and your problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE 'character'
(
character_id VarChar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
name VarChar(30) NOT NULL,
sex VarChar(7) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
hair VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
eye VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
skin VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
body VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
from VarChar(20) NOT NULL
) engine=innobd;
```

you're trying to use a reserved word so you need to add backtick to the table name, My suggestion is to change the table name, and avoid using reserved words

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. The table name "character" should be characters, character is a reserved word
2. The field name "from" should be different than the SQL keyword FROM

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE characters
(
character_id VarChar(15) PRIMARY KEY,
name VarChar(30) NOT NULL,
sex VarChar(7) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
hair VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
eye VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
skin VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
body VarChar(12) NOT NULL,
fromX VarChar(20) NOT NULL
) engine=innobd;
```

Hope this help.